# R: How to create a conditional column indirectly based on a non-static amount of other columns, in a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following `data.table`:

```
     Name    x    y   h 120Hz 800Hz 1000Hz 1200Hz
1: Tower1 1354  829 245     0     8      7      0
2: Tower2 2654  234 285     7     0      3      0
3: Tower3  822 3040 256     0     4      0      9
4: Tower4  987 2747 250     0     6      5      3
5: Tower5 1953 1739 301     0     0      8      2
```

You can create it with:

```
DT <- data.table(Name = c("Tower1", "Tower2", "Tower3", "Tower4", "Tower5"),
                 x = c(1354,2654,822,987,1953),
                 y = c(829,234,3040,2747,1739),
                 h = c(245,285,256,250,301),
                 `120Hz` = c(0,7,0,0,0),
                 `800Hz` = c(8,0,4,6,0),
                 `1000Hz` = c(7,3,0,5,8),
                 `1200Hz` = c(0,0,9,3,2))
```

In reality, it came from a previous, larger `data.table`. The last four columns were auto-generated from that other `data.table` using `dcast`, so there is no way to know beforehand the number or the names of the columns after column h. This is important.

The final goal is to create another column named "Range", whose value for each row depends on the values in the columns after column "h", as it follows:

Consider the following associations between frequencies and ranges. These are the only stablished associations and are static, so this information could be stored as a pre-defined `data.table`.

```
assoc <- data.table(Frq = c("800Hz", "1000Hz", "1200Hz"),
                    Rng = c(750,850,950))
```

For each one of the four columns after column "h", the code should check if the column name exists in `assoc`. If so, AND if the value in that column for the row in question in `DT` is NOT zero, then the code considers the respective Rng value (from `assoc`). After checking all four columns, the code should return the MAXIMUM of the ranges considered and store in the new column "Range".

---

My approach:

Create one auxiliar column for each frequency column:

```
DT <- DT[, paste0(colnames(DT)[5:ncol(DT)],'_r') := 0]
```

Then I could use a conditional structure that does the algorithm described above. Let's take for example column 800Hz_r. This column checks the value in column 800Hz. If that value is not zero for the row in question, then it returns 750. At the end, the column Range simply takes the maximum of the previous 4 columns, the ones ending with _f. There's where I'm stuck, I can't find an useful command to do so. Everything I've tried throws me some error.

Finally, the auxiliary _f columns should be deleted. If anyone knows a way to do it without creating auxiliar columns it would be much better.

This is the expected result (prior to deletion of auxiliary columns):

```
     Name    x    y   h 120Hz 800Hz 1000Hz 1200Hz 120Hz_f 800Hz_f 1000Hz_f 1200Hz_f Range
1: Tower1 1354  829 245     0     8      7      0       0     750      850        0    850
2: Tower2 2654  234 285     7     0      3      0       0       0      850        0    850
3: Tower3  822 3040 256     0     4      0      9       0     750        0      950    950
4: Tower4  987 2747 250     0     6      5      3       0     750      850      950    950
5: Tower5 1953 1739 301     0     0      8      2       0       0      850      950    950
```

---

NOTE: The reason why there could be frequency columns that don't appear in assoc is because the original data could have typos. In this example, the column 120Hz would always generate only zeros in column 120Hz_f and thus it can never get to be considered for the maximum Range. That's ok.

Comment: Using your example could you give us the expected output?

Comment: For example, it is not clear if the "maximum of the ranges" corresponds to the maximum assoc$Rng or to the columns in DT.

Comment: @lmo The maximum of the values in columns ending with _f. Those values come from assoc. I updated the question so you can see the wanted result.

Comment: I think you should do this computation while your data is in long form, before the `dcast`. Generally, if you find that you are doing computations across columns like this, you should use a long table or a matrix instead of a wide table.

Comment: @Frank I can't because there are character columns. The reason why I used  `dcast` is because prior to this stage, I had a longer data.table which had another column named Frequency. For this example, it had 15 rows named Tower1, with identical information in x,y and h columns. 8 of them said '800Hz' in Frequency and 7 said '1000Hz', so I used `dcast ` to count the number of rows in each category of Frequency and then deleted redundant rows.

Comment: You can count rows like `DT[, .N, by=Frequency]` in long format; you don't need to `dcast`/make crosstabs and I think it's generally not a good idea unless it's the final step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A back and forth to long format can make this work:

```
dcast(melt(DT, measure.vars=patterns("Hz$"))[assoc, on = c(variable = 'Frq')
                                                  , Rng := i.Rng * (value != 0)],
      Name + x + y + h ~ variable, max, value.var='Rng')[,
  do.call(function(...) pmax(..., na.rm = T), .SD), .SDcols = `120Hz`:`1200Hz`]
#[1] 850 850 950 950 950
```

Or you can avoid creating the intermediate columns if you loop over `assoc`:

```
DT[, Range := -Inf]

assoc[, {DT[, Range := pmax(Range, (get(Frq) != 0) * Rng)]; NULL}, by = Frq]

DT
#     Name    x    y   h 120Hz 800Hz 1000Hz 1200Hz Range
#1: Tower1 1354  829 245     0     8      7      0   850
#2: Tower2 2654  234 285     7     0      3      0   850
#3: Tower3  822 3040 256     0     4      0      9   950
#4: Tower4  987 2747 250     0     6      5      3   950
#5: Tower5 1953 1739 301     0     0      8      2   950
```

Comment: The second method is just what I wanted. Works like a charm, big thanks. Just a little question. I'm not familiarized with that structure but it's clearly not a standard variable assignment. Is there something we can do to avoid the console output? Im talking about  `assoc[, {DT[, Range := pmax(Range, (get(Frq) != 0) * Rng)]; NULL}, by = Frq]` which displays  `Empty data.table (0 rows) of 1 col: Frq`

Comment: @JAR yep - wrap it in `invisible`

Answer (score 0):

It is not exactly as you intend but my motto is when the algorithm does not fit the data, then format the data to the algorithm.

A bit long but simple to implement.

I melt DT with the following code and use the convert the Hz into numeric with removing the "Hz" and converting into numeric.

```
a <- melt(DT,id.vars=1:4)[value>0][,crit:=as.numeric(gsub("Hz","",variable))]
```

to get something like:

```
##> a
##      Name    x    y   h variable value crit
## 1: Tower1 1354  829 245    800Hz     8  800
## 2: Tower1 1354  829 245   1000Hz     7 1000
## 3: Tower2 2654  234 285    120Hz     7  120
## 4: Tower2 2654  234 285   1000Hz     3 1000
## 5: Tower3  822 3040 256    800Hz     4  800
## 6: Tower3  822 3040 256   1200Hz     9 1200
## 7: Tower4  987 2747 250    800Hz     6  800
## 8: Tower4  987 2747 250   1000Hz     5 1000
## 9: Tower4  987 2747 250   1200Hz     3 1200
## 10: Tower5 1953 1739 301   1000Hz     8 1000
## 11: Tower5 1953 1739 301   1200Hz     2 1200
```

Then find the max by Tower.

```
## > a[,.(crit=max(crit)),by=Name]
##    Name crit
## 1: Tower1 1000
## 2: Tower2 1000
## 3: Tower3 1200
## 4: Tower4 1200
## 5: Tower5 1200
```

Then merge it back with a

```
b <- merge(setkey(a,Name,crit),setkey(a[,.(crit=max(crit)),by=Name],Name,crit))
```

To get something like

```
## > b
## Name crit    x    y   h variable value
## 1: Tower1 1000 1354  829 245   1000Hz     7
## 2: Tower2 1000 2654  234 285   1000Hz     3
## 3: Tower3 1200  822 3040 256   1200Hz     9
## 4: Tower4 1200  987 2747 250   1200Hz     3
## 5: Tower5 1200 1953 1739 301   1200Hz     2
```

Then merge b with assoc

```
## > merge(b,assoc,by.x="variable",by.y="Frq")
## variable   Name crit    x    y   h value Rng
## 1:   1000Hz Tower1 1000 1354  829 245     7 850
## 2:   1000Hz Tower2 1000 2654  234 285     3 850
## 3:   1200Hz Tower3 1200  822 3040 256     9 950
## 4:   1200Hz Tower4 1200  987 2747 250     3 950
## 5:   1200Hz Tower5 1200 1953 1739 301     2 950
```